# Обмен данными между программами

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

Есть программа на С# (MonoDevelop, Linux), которая может при запуске управлять демоном (старт/стоп/статус). Как можно осуществить передачу данных между ними? (Например, родительская программа пишет в файл, а демон читает из него, нужно синхронизировать потоки, чтоб не было ошибки чтения, БЕЗ TRY/CATCH)

Comment: я, конечно, далек от темы... Но что было опробовано? ,Первое что приходит в голову - мутекс, база данных (если эти данные должны обрабатыватся обома сторонами), сокеты

Comment: @Andrew, как синхронизировать мьютексы между двумя разными приложениями?

Comment: @Andrew, бд не подойдёт, а вот насчёт сокетов хз, не слышал

Comment: мьютекс доступен только из одного приложения для изменений. Из документации: You can use the WaitHandle.WaitOne method to request ownership of a mutex.

Comment: Сеть, unix sockets, message queues, shared memory, FIFOs — выбирай не хочу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как можно осуществить передачу данных между ними?

На самом деле это очень большой вопрос. В POSIX системах есть целый раздел: IPC - Inter Process Communication - взаимодействие между процессами. Подход с обменом даннвми черз общий файл - самое плохое решение. В рамках POSIX существует много различных способов:

1. Общая память
2. Очереди сообщений
3. Каналы данных - Pipe
4. Сигналы
5. Сокеты UNIX

Короче - очень много чего. Unix (в отличии от DOS/Windows) изначально создавался как МНОГОпроцессная система. Поэтому средства IPC в Linux черезвычайно развиты.

Есть замечательная книга на эту тему "UNIX: взаимодействие процессов", Уильям Ричард Стивенс. Это, можно сказать, талмуд по IPC. Соответствующей толщины.

Я думаю, что для вашей задачи самым простым решением будет использование очереди сообщений. Но это уже - вам решать.